# How to create a personalised WindowFn in google dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I'd like to create a different `WindowFn` in a such way to assign Windows to any of my input elements based on another field instead of based on my input entry's timestamp. I know the pre-defined `WindowFn`'s from Google DataFlow SDK use the timestamp as a criteria to assign window.

More specifically I'd like to create a kind of `SlidingWindows` but instead of considering timestamp as the Window assignment criteria I'd like to consider another field as that criteria.

How could I create my customised `WindowFn`? What are the points that I should consider when creating my own `WindowFn`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new WindowFn, you just need to inherit from [WindowFn](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.java) or a subclass and override the various abstract methods.

In your case, you don't need window merging, so you can inherit from NonMergingWindowFn, and your code could look something like

```
public class MyWindowFn extends NonMergingWindowFn<ElementT, IntervalWindow> {
  public Collection<W> assignWindows(AssignContext c) {
    return setOfWindowsElementShouldBeIn(c.element());
  }

  public boolean isCompatible(WindowFn other) {
    return other instanceof MyWindowFn;
  }

  public Coder<IntervalWindow> windowCoder() {
    return IntervalWindow.getCoder();
  }

  public W getSideInputWindow(final BoundedWindow window) {
    // You may not need this if you won't ever be using PCollections windowed 
    // with this as side inputs.  If that's the case, just throw.
    // Otherwise you'll need to figure out how to map the main input windows
    // into the windows generated by this WindowFn.
  }
}
```