# Predefined (and large) windows? Any stream processing frameworks support this?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

All the examples I see of windowing involve *defining* the windows. E.g., tumbling 1-minute windows, or sliding 1-minute windows, etc. In my situation, all my data has timestamped events, but that's not the primary interest.

All my data also has an associated **period** that I do not have control over. That is the desired window in my case. The periods are time-based, but they vary from 2-3 weeks, roughly.

So, if I look at just the period of a stream of values might look like this (almost everything from the current period, a few stragglers from the last period early on in current period),

```
... PERIOD 6, PERIOD 5, PERIOD 6, PERIOD 6, PERIOD 6, PERIOD 6, ...
```

It's not clear to me how to handle this situation in terms of watermarks/triggers/etc? If I'm understanding all this terminology correctly I've thought of something like this: the watermark for `PERIOD N` occurs when the first event with `PERIOD (N+1)` is processed. The lateness horizon (for garbage collecting state) for the `PERIOD N` window can be 1-2 days after the timestamp of the first event with `PERIOD (N+1)`. I'd like triggers to be `accumulating` and every 5 minutes (ideally, I'd like this trigger duration to be increasing: more frequent at beginning of the window, less frequent as time passes).

I'm trying to use terminology from this article, https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102 sorry if it's incorrect

I'm particularly confused about how watermarks seem to be continuous and based on event-time. In my case, I have both event-time (timestamp) and event-time (period). If I'm understanding this correctly, the curve of my situation (as in the above article) would look like a step-function?

I haven't yet picked a stream processing framework to use. Does my situation make sense for any of them? Does this require a lot of custom logic? Does any framework make this easier? Is this a known problem with a name?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For your use case, if using Beam, I'd look into writing your own window as advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897452/how-to-create-a-personalised-windowfn-in-google-dataflow or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300180/creating-custom-windowing-function-in-apache-beam

Comment: @GuillemXercavins I looked at those examples but I'm honestly still not sure how to do this. 

This requires implementing a BoundedWindow function, which requires a `maxTimestamp()` method. But, my situation doesn't have such a thing

Comment: BoundedWindow class I should say

Answer (score 0):

In Flink, one way to achieve this is to use the processing time window for aggregation. Then you use a rich map function to maintain the accumulated counts before the window. In the end, you sink the aggregates to long-term data storage

You can take a look at my [blog post](https://klaviyo.tech/scaling-klaviyos-real-time-analytics-system-with-stream-processing-4b3bb87cd6b5) where we did something similar to this. Take a look at Section `A peek into Milestone Two`